# add the values of two columns in pandas using apply and map

Tags: python, pandas

Basically i was trying to add two columns data and reflect it on another column and the data was below

```
data = {'name': ['Jason', 'Molly', 'Tina', 'Jake', 'Amy'], 
        'year': [2012, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2014], 
        'reports': [4, 24, 31, 2, 3],
        'coverage': [25, 94, 57, 62, 70]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index = ['Cochice', 'Pima', 'Santa Cruz', 'Maricopa', 'Yuma'])
df


        coverage    name    reports year
Cochice    25      Jason      4    2012
Pima       94      Molly     24    2012
Santa Cruz 57      Tina      31    2013
Maricopa   62      Jake      2     2014
Yuma       70       Amy      3     2014
```

I am using above data frame for testing and I want to add the data of two columns `coverage` and `reports` and replace it with one column as below

```
df[["coverage"]] = df[["coverage"]].apply(lambda value:add(df["coverage"], df["reports"]))
```

and my result should be

```
        coverage       name reports year
Cochice    25+4=29     Jason      4    2012
Pima       94+24       Molly     24    2012
Santa Cruz 57+31       Tina      31    2013
Maricopa   62+2        Jake      2     2014
Yuma       70+3        Amy       3     2014
```

But it was not working, can anyone please let me know what's wrong in the above code ?

### Edit

My add function

```
def add(one, two):
  return one + two
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need simply [`add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.add.html):

```
df["coverage"] = df["coverage"].add(df["reports"])
print (df)
            coverage   name  reports  year
Cochice           29  Jason        4  2012
Pima             118  Molly       24  2012
Santa Cruz        88   Tina       31  2013
Maricopa          64   Jake        2  2014
Yuma              73    Amy        3  2014
```

Or:

```
df["coverage"] = df["coverage"] + df["reports"]
print (df)
            coverage   name  reports  year
Cochice           29  Jason        4  2012
Pima             118  Molly       24  2012
Santa Cruz        88   Tina       31  2013
Maricopa          64   Jake        2  2014
Yuma              73    Amy        3  2014
```

Your code need `axis=1`:

```
def add(one, two):
  return one + two

df["coverage"] = df.apply(lambda x :add(x["coverage"], x["reports"]), axis=1)
print (df)
            coverage   name  reports  year
Cochice           29  Jason        4  2012
Pima             118  Molly       24  2012
Santa Cruz        88   Tina       31  2013
Maricopa          64   Jake        2  2014
Yuma              73    Amy        3  2014
```

Comment: basically add is the custom method i have written and i want to replace it with another lambda function that splits the text etc.,, what about axis and why it is used ?

Comment: I think better is use `add` because this function is vectorized. But if need custom function and `add` or something similar function cannot be used, need slowier apply.

Comment: can we write the same function using map ?

Comment: `map` ? I think not, the best is `add`

Comment: I have taken add as an example to illustrate my scenario, but actually in place of add i will design another function the splits and do some processing etc., and i am asking the same format using map ?

Comment: `map` is used if need replace values in column bu some `dict` or by `Series`, if need apply some function, use `apply`.

Comment: can we delete some rows based on a condition using apply or map ?

Comment: I am not sure if understand, but I think yes.

Comment: can you provide me a link for doing that if you don't think it was a new question ?

Comment: I think the best is use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), so `apply` is not necessary, but it is possible implement to custom function if necessary. Please check link.